# Is there a css or html element that will force push content down to the bottom of a page?

Tags: html, css

I am curious if there is a css or html element that will force push content down to the bottom of a page. I would like some content to be at the bottom of the page below some php generated content that I cannot alter.

Comment: There is no one element or property that will do this if that's the answer you are looking for.

Comment: these are not the elements that you are looking for...

Comment: Do you mean bottom of the *page* or bottom of the *window*?

Comment: I mean the bottom of the page, but not below the footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS - this won't push other content out of the way, but it will go to the bottom of the page.

```
.bottomElement {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are basically looking for a sticky footer:
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/